# Consistent choice of elements in inverse directed system

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Is there some theory related to this...

Let $(\{X_\alpha\}_\alpha,f_{\alpha\beta}:X_\beta\rightarrow X_\alpha\}_{\alpha\preceq\beta})$ be an inverse directed system of non-empty sets resp. surjective functions.  Under which circumstances (axiom of choice assumed) do we have a choice $\{x_\alpha\}_\alpha$ of elements in $X_\alpha$ which is consistent in the sense of $f_{\alpha\beta}(x_\beta)=x_\alpha$?  Or are there some prominent counterexamples?

Comment: It *really* depends a lot of the sets.

Comment: OK, I see.  Do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: If it came from a natural place, then there must be some natural constraints on these sets, just add them in.

Comment: It's kind of hard...  I was thinking about this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130294/directed-limits-of-topological-spaces-and-embeddings but in the category of locally convex sets, so for my question the $X_\alpha$ are sets of neighbourhoods that don't intersect a given set and $f_{\alpha\beta}$ passes them down to embedded subspaces, but I can't see any noteable structure on the level of sets here, maybe I indeed chose the wrong approach for the problem.

Comment: Maybe. Remember that topology in general has deep connections to the axiom of choice, like Tychonoff's theorem for example. So doing topology is much easier when you just assume the axiom of choice anyway. Without it you have to start carrying around all sort of strange assumptions. It's unclean.

Comment: I assume the axiom of choice!  If it can be used to answer my question, then I overlooked it, sorry!

Comment: The axiom of choice tag is traditionally used (in questions like this one) as a hint that the answer should explain how much choice is needed for proving the result. Hence my original comment.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I came up with a counterexample at least.  (I didn't actually think that the assumption would hold but it still took me some time to confirm this.)

Let our directed set be $\aleph_1$ and $X_\beta$ consisting of all finite sequences of ordinals $\beta_0<\beta_1<\cdots<\beta_{n-1}\le\beta<\beta_n<\aleph_1$.  Then let $f_{\alpha\beta}(\beta_0,\ldots,\beta_n)$ equal the unique prefix $(\beta_0,\ldots,\beta_k)$ that is contained in $X_\alpha$.  Clearly this forms an inverse directed system and also the $f_{\alpha\beta}$ are surjective.  But assuming there is some consistent choice $s_\alpha\in X_\alpha$, we can see that the $s_\alpha$ get arbitrary long, which contradicts regularity of $\aleph_1$ and the fact that the $f_{\alpha\beta}$ do not increase the length of sequences.