# Open cells of a CW complex are disjoint

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

My definition for a CW complex is any space built by the following inductive procedure:

- A $0$ dimensional CW Complex is a topological space with the discrete topology.
- Let $X_n$ be an $n$-dimensional CW complex and $\phi_n: \amalg S_n \to X_{n}$. The corresponding $n+1$ dimensional CW complex $X_{n+1}$ is given by the following pushout diagram:

\begin{align*}
 \require{AMScd}
 \begin{CD}
  \amalg S^n @>{}>> \amalg D^{n+1}\\
  @V{\phi_n}VV @VV{}V \\
  X_n @>>{}> X_{n+1}
 \end{CD}
\end{align*}

An infinite dimensional CW complex $X$ can be formed as a colimit of finite ones. Given an inclusion $D^n \hookrightarrow \amalg D^n$ the characteristic map $\tau: D^n \to X$ is the map induced on $D^n$ s.t. the relavent diagram commutes. $\tau(D^n)$ is a cell and $\tau(int(D^n))$ is the corresponding open cell.

I get the definition and i have a solid intuition about CW complexes. I have a problem though whenever i try to prove something formal about them. I get confused by the diagrams. The question i'm stuck on now is:

**How do I prove in the most simple and elegant way that open cells are disjoint?**

Comment: Take $x\in X_{n+1}$ that belongs to $2$ open two cells. By deifnition, this means that $x$ comes from (at least) two points in $\coprod \text{int}(D^{n+1})$, but this is impossible because the gluing is only along their boundaries (that is, points in different $D^{n+1}$s cannot coincide in $X_{n+1}$, only points in their boundaries $S^n$).

Comment: @Sonner I get the verbal explanation, but whenever i try to go all the way i get confused like hell. For example, what if the cells are not of the same dimension? I need to see once and for all a totally explicit proof so it won't seem to me like unwarranted intuition.

Comment: But when you go up $1$ dimension, the construction is to glue what you have with some $D_{n+1}$ only along their boundaries, so that the new open cells are disjoint from what you had before (points in the open cells are not identified to anything, old or new).

Answer (score 3):

I put some subscripts to the balls in order to distinguish them from each other. Here $\alpha$ uniquely determines the ball $D_\alpha^n$, so there is not really the need to keep the superscript $n$. This way, $\phi_n$ restricts on $S_\alpha^n$ to a gluing map $\phi_\alpha:S_\alpha\to X_n$. Let $r_\alpha$ denote the characteristic map for $D_\alpha$, and let $i_n:X_n\to X^{n+1}$ be the map induced by the pushout square.

\begin{align*}
 \require{AMScd}
 \begin{CD}
  \amalg S_\alpha^n @>{\amalg i_\alpha}>> \amalg D_\alpha^{n+1}\\
  @V{\phi_n}VV @VV{r^{n+1}}V \\
  X_n @>{i_n}>> X_{n+1}
 \end{CD}
\end{align*}

It can be shown that since $\amalg i_\alpha$ is a (closed) inclusion, $i_n$ is a (closed) inclusion as well. This again imlies that the canonical map $j_n$ from $X_n$ to the colimit $X=\varinjlim X_n$ is a (closed) inclusion (cf. [Directed limits of topological spaces and embeddings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130294/directed-limits-of-topological-spaces-and-embeddings)).
Now if $x$ is a point in the CW complex $X$, there is a minimal $m$ such that $x\in j_{m+1}(X_{m+1})$. Note that $X_{m+1}$ is a disjoint union of two sets: $i_m(X_m)$ and $r^{m+1}(\amalg \operatorname{int}(D_\alpha^{m+1}))$, and
$$r^{m+1}(\amalg \operatorname{int}(D_\alpha^{m+1})) = \amalg r_\alpha(\text{int}(D_\alpha))$$
Since $x\notin j_m(X_m)$, it must lie in one open cell $j_{m+1}(r_\beta(\text{int}(D_\beta^{m+1})))$. If $j_p(r_\gamma(\text{int}(D_\gamma^p)))$ is a cell with $p>m+1$, then this cell is disjoint from $j_{p-1}(X_{p-1})$, which contains $j_{m+1}(X_{m+1})$ and thus $x$, so $j_{m+1}(r_\beta(\text{int}(D_\beta^{m+1})))$ is the unique cell which contains $x$.